# What is the release date for Rakudo Star (perl6)?

Tags: raku, parrot

If a specific release date is not available (as I suspect it is not), can you provide resources for tracking how close it is to the desired feature set that allows release.

I'm not necessarily asking for a percentage gauge, or X of Y features completed list.  A list of bugs marked in whichever section of the perl RT instance that's tracking Rakudo bugs would meet my criteria, even more so if the list is dynamic (I.e. it's a list of bugs tagged in some manner, not a static list of ticket numbers).  If there are only a few planned features left to be finished/tested before it's considered ready for final testing, listing those would also be sufficient.

Comment: It's here! http://blogs.perl.org/users/coke/2010/07/announce-rakudo-star---a-useful-usable-early-adopter-distribution-of-perl-6.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[As per this post](http://rakudo.org/node/68) on 04/08/2010, the first major release of "Rakudo Star 1.0" **is tentatively aimed at Q2 2010** (original plan was around April 2010 but was shifted due to personal circumstances involving lead developer).

Also, on 4/22/2010 they announced an April development release of Rakudo. That announcement stated: "This is not the "Rakudo Star" release announced for Q2 2010 -- we expect that to be shipped in June."

Not sure if this is good enough for you as a measure of progress, but they have a ["Spectest progress" chart](http://rakudo.org/status). That same status page has a list of things that work and don't work in Rakudo. The latter is dated 4/11/2010.

Comment: June is better than nothing, and thus better than what I knew before.  I'd love some way to see the open tickets that are blocking Rakudo Star, but I can't see a way to do that in rt.perl.org.  I guess I should ask on IRC.

Answer (score 9):

Latest tentative date is [July 29th 2010](http://use.perl.org/~pmichaud/journal/40407)

And it has been [released](http://rakudo.org/node/75)!

Answer (score 7):

As for the planned features, please see the [ROADMAP](https://web.archive.org/web/20100226101648/http://github.com:80/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/docs/ROADMAP).

The number of stars in the "Really important items" and "Ought to have items" are an estimation of how much work is needed to implement that particular feature.

Update: If you are interested in Perl 6 development, this thread might also interest you: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=837535

Comment: @moritz - Ah, the second half of what I was looking for.  Thanks!